# Can Windows 7 conflict with another Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multi-boot

I installed Windows 7 and then I made a backup image of this Windows 7 and put it on another partition. So now I have dual boot of Windows 7, however I noticed that stuff like Visual Studio is not installing.

So I am wondering can they conflict with each other since they are copies of each other even though they are on different partitions?

Comment: Question too vague.  What does "stuff like Visual Studio is not installing" mean?  Where are you installing it?  What message do you receive when it fails?  Do you actually own multiple licenses or are you illegally using a second copy of Windows 7?  What version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with restoring an exact backup image to another partition is that a lot of programs will already be configured to write to locations on `C:` when you are in fact now using `D:` for example. However installing new programs shouldn't cause problems as you can specify an install path. What errors are you receiving? Did you run the installer as Administrator?